# Only Ctrl+c not working. I have windows 7? (Ctrl-v, ctrl-x etc work good)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Only Ctrl+c not working. I have windows 7? (Ctrl-v, ctrl-x etc work good)

This not work in all programs (Office, Firefox, Chrome etc)
Thanks

Comment: Does your `c` work?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/215595/keyboard-shortcuts-such-as-ctrl-c-ctrl-v-and-ctrl-z-not-working-in-word-2010-on try here the solutions,elaborate ur query with more info

Comment: Yes - my c work. CCCC  :-)

Comment: Hi blueberry. I try your solution and this work good.
I didn't try this before because in this problem all the shortcut not work.Thanks.
If you add it as answer I approve it.
If not, My question is solved. I can delete it if you want.
thanks all

Comment: @yoni have a good day mate,it already have been answered there so no issues friend ,happy its resolved :)

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as duplicate, this question is not specific to Word but OP is seeing issues with all programs.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that other software is hijacking your hotkeys.
For example Catalyst Control Center was hijacking Alt+Shift+C.
Other solution would be revmap your copy shortcut to Ctrl+g or other.